# python3.4 Pyqt4 web request asyncio

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-asyncio

Is it possible to perform in asynchrone(like with asyncio) web requests under Pyqt4 (QwebPage)?

For example, how can I call multiple urls in parallel with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import sys
import signal

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class Crawler( QWebPage ):
    def __init__(self, url):
        QWebPage.__init__( self )
        self._url = url
        self.content = ''

    def crawl( self ):
        signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL )
        self.connect( self, SIGNAL( 'loadFinished(bool)' ), self._finished_loading )
        self.mainFrame().load( QUrl( self._url ) )

    def _finished_loading( self, result ):
        self.content = self.mainFrame().toHtml()
        print(self.content)
        sys.exit( 0 )

    def main():
        app = QApplication( sys.argv )
        crawler = Crawler( self._url, self._file )
        crawler.crawl()
        sys.exit( app.exec_() )

if __name__ == '__main__':
     crawl = Crawler( 'http://www.example.com')
     crawl.main()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make `self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(self._url))` working through asyncio, sorry -- the method implemented in Qt itself.

But you can install [quamash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash) event loop and asynchronously call [aiohttp.request](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/v0.11.0/client.html#make-a-request) coroutine to get web pages.

The way doesn't work with `QWebPage` though.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your reply. If I replace QwebPage by aiohttp, it will possible to perform async call? Or I need to modify all my code?

Comment: The answer depends on your needs.
If async getting HTTP Requests for later analyzing satisfies your requirements (e.g. you writing something like Scrapy with Qt interface for example) -- aiohttp can help you.

Comment: Have you got an example of using PyQT4 with aiohttp? Because I've try to use both together but it does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are already done asynchronously, so you all you need to do is create multiple instances of `QWebPage`.

Here's a simple demo based on your example script:

```
import sys, signal
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

urls = [
    'http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html',
    'http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html',
    'http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebinspector.html',
    'http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html',
    'http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html',
    'http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html',
    ]

class Crawler(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url, identifier):
        super(Crawler, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._finished_loading)
        self._id = identifier
        self._url = url
        self.content = ''

    def crawl(self):
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(self._url))

    def _finished_loading(self, result):
        self.content = self.mainFrame().toHtml()
        print('[%d] %s' % (self._id, self._url))
        print(self.content[:250].rstrip(), '...')
        print()
        self.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication( sys.argv )
    signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    crawlers = []
    for index, url in enumerate(urls):
        crawlers.append(Crawler(url, index))
        crawlers[-1].crawl()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```